# RxSwift - Chaining Observables and Singles

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, chaining, method-chaining

I need to call a sequences of function to get all the information I need for a notification. First subscribe which opens up the session, then `queryNotification` to listen on all the incoming notifications, and once a notification is received, need to call `getNotificationAttrs` with the `notificationId` returned in `queryNotification`, then call `getAppAttributes` with `appIdentifier` returned in `getNotificationAttrs` and I need the combined result of `queryNotification`, `getNotificationAttrs` and `getAppAttributes`. How the functions look like are below:

```
func subscribeNotification() -> Single<Info>
func queryNotification() -> Observable<Notification>
func getNotificationAttrs(uid: UInt32, attributes: [Attribute]) -> Single<NotificationAttributes>
func getAppAttributes(appIdentifier: String, attributes: [AppAttribute]) -> Single<NotificationAppAttributes>
```

The tricky part is that `queryNotification` returns Observable and both `getNotificationAttrs` and `getAppAttributes` return Single. What I have in mind of chaining them together is like:

```
subscribeNotification()
    .subscribe(onSuccess: { info in
        queryNotification()
            .flatMap({ notification in 
                return getNotificationAttributes(uid: notification.uid, attributes: [.appIdentifier, .content])
            })
            .flatMap({ notifAttrs
                return getAppAttributes(appIdentifier: notifAttrs.appIdentifier, attributes: [.displayName])
            })
            .subscribe {
                // have all the result from last two calls
            }
       })
```

Is this doable? Any direction is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Based on what you have so far, it looks like you need your `Info` and your `NotificationAppAttributes` in the final subscribe. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious and IMHO correct solution is to promote your `Single` into an `Observable`. Also, I'm not a fan of the first `subscribe` where it is. You end up with an indentation pyramid.

I'm following your comments about needing the values from all of `queryNotification()`, `getNotificationAttrs(did:attributes:)` and `getAppAttributes(appIdentifier:attributes:)`...

```
let query = subscribeNotification()
    .asObservable()
    .flatMap { _ in queryNotification() }
    .share(replay: 1)

let attributes = query
    .flatMap { getNotificationAttrs(uid: $0.uid, attributes: [.appIdentifier, .content]) }
    .share(replay: 1)

let appAttributes = attributes
    .flatMap { getAppAttributes(appIdentifier: $0.appIdentifier, attributes: [.displayName]) }

Observable.zip(query, attributes, appAttributes)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (query, attributes, appAttributes) in

    })
```

The above will follow the steps you outlined and the subscribe will get called every time a new notification is emitted.

Also notice how the above reads quite a bit like synchronous code would (just with some extra wrapping.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the final block I actually need the result of `queryNotification`, `getNotificationAttrs` and `getAppAttributes`. Also, why `.share(replay: 1)` is needed? Thanks!

Comment: Adjusted so you get all three values. The `.share(replay: 1)` is in there because whenever you have more than one subscription to an Observable, each will get its own values (i.e., if a network call or other side-effect is used, the side effect will happen once for each subscription.) I assume that would not be good in this context. If I'm wrong, then you don't need them.